Exercise 2.2.1 from An introduction to Riemann-Finsler geometry
I have stuck in the Exercise 2.2.1 of the book An Introduction to Riemann-Finsler Geometry by Bao, Chern and Shen.

Verify the following statement: (c) $v_i^\alpha y^i=0$ and (d) $u_\alpha^i F_{y^i}=0$.

Here $(M,F)$ is a Finsler manifold with Finsler metric $F$ with the following relations:
\begin{eqnarray*}
e_a &=& u^i_a\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} &=& v^a_i e_a,\\
\omega^a &=& v_i^a dx^i,\\
dx^i &=& u^i_a \omega^a,\\
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\{e_a\}$ is the special $g$-orthonormal basis for $\pi^*TM$ and $\{\omega^a\}$ is the special basis dual to $\{e_a\}$ on $\pi^* T^*M$ provided $e_n=l:=\frac{y^i}{F}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ (the distinguished section) and $\omega^n=\omega$ (the Hilbert form).
As a beginner to this subject I am unable to find an initiation to the solution.
Further I do not know why $\alpha$ is used as an index, where as in the past two exercises indices like $a,b$ were used. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
